# Infinispan: ClusterCacheLoader does not support preloading

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

We have a need for a restart-persistent cache.
The main goal is to preload as much data as possible on startup.

Thus requirements are:

- preload from disk storage
- preload from neighbor node that already running with hot cache

It looked like Infinispan could be a suitable choice here, but I found following in the documentation:

> 5.8. Cluster cache loader
>
> The ClusterCacheLoader does not support preloading(preload=true). It also won’t provide state if fetchPersistentSate=true.

Is there any other way to configure Infinispan to preload data from a neighbor node on startup, except writing custom Cache Loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClusterCacheLoader` is normally used in invalidation mode, where preloading isn't very useful.

It sounds like you need a replicated cache. As long as you don't disable state transfer, a replicated cache will receive the existing entries on startup from the already running nodes.